# Enforcing BLE security from Android Application

Tags: android, security, bluetooth-lowenergy

Is there a way to enforce security of BLE from application layer in andriod?

I understand BLE stack in implemented in the chips. I was wondering if there is a way for us to control parameters in BLE chip to get desired level of security. For example,in BLE size of encryption key is negotiable. Is there a way to only enforce encryption key size from application?

Comment: Secure from what attack? Reminder from: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le `Caution: When a user pairs their device with another device using BLE, the data that's communicated between the two devices is accessible to all apps on the user's device. For this reason, if your app captures sensitive data, you should implement app-layer security to protect the privacy of that data.`

Answer (score 0):

No you can't, which is in my opinion a big flaw in the API.

However if you use L2CAP channels you can at least require that the link shall be encrypted, but not at a particular level. Use either https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice#createL2capChannel(int) or https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice#createInsecureL2capChannel(int).